# How to check test cases if no verification possible

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm learning about unit testing and I came across the problem to create a final check on wether a test case is correct or not. Usually I try to create a verification, like through an `assertEquals()`. But what is recommended to do when it's not possible to test it like this?

I have a class like this:

```
public class Landlord {

    private Map<String, ChannelHandlerContext> currentOccupier;
    private static Landlord instance;

    public Landlord() {
        currentOccupier = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static Landlord getInstance {
        //return instance
    }

    public void add(Occupier occupier){
        currentOccupier.put("test", occupier.getChannelHandlerContext());    
    }
}
```

And now I try to test the method like this:

```
public class LandlordTest {

    private Landlord landlord;
    @Mock
    private Occupier occupier;
    @Mock
    private ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        occupier = mock(Occupier.class);
        channelHandlerContext = mock(ChannelHandlerContext.class);

        landlord = Landlord.getInstance();

        when(occupier.getChannelHandlerContext()).thenReturn(channelHandlerContext);
    }

    public void add(Occupier occupier){
        addedOccupier.put(occupier.getChannelHandlerContext()); 
        //adding succeded
    }

}
```

Maybe in this short example it wouldn't be needed to test it, but is there a way to verify that the add method was successful? Normally in these kind of cases, I'd try something like: `assertEquals(currentOccupier.size(), 1)`, but here I can't access the hashMap of the instance to do it like this. Is there another way to verify the correct behaviour of adding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `assertEquals(currentOccupier.size(), 1)` is really not enough.
You want to assert that the map contains the entry that you added in the map.
That assertion is too shallow : it doesn't check for the entry neither the value of the key nor the value of the value.
You should do something like :

```
ChannelHandlerContext actualContext = landLord.get("test");
assertSame(addedContext, actualContext);
// or assertEquals if the instances may differ because you do some defensive copy in add()
```

Note also that you mock here some things that should not need to be mocked : `occupier` and `channelHandlerContext` make part of your model. You should be able to provide  "normal" instances of them in the frame of the test.

Here you have broadly two ways to perform that :

1) adding a public method in the class to under test to find an `ChannelHandlerContext` :

```
public ChannelHandlerContext get(String name){
    currentOccupier.get(name);    
}
```

Do that **only** if providing this access is acceptable.
If you cannot add a public method, add a package level method as this doesn't make part of the exposed API.

2) use reflection api (essentially `Class.getDeclaredField(String)` and `Field.get()`) to retrieve the map instance from the instance under test and then assert that it contains the expected `ChannelHandlerContext` instance for  the "test" key.

Comment: So it's not enough to test if the user was added to a list? What else is to check, like verifying that the user is actually the same?

Comment: Exactly. I updated with a  simple example to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me with that!